# Root domain works but subdomain doesn't - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, azure-static-web-app

I created a static web app on Azure and connected my domain via Azure DNS zone.
I added all the necessary records and my root domain works with https.

I also added cname record for www but when I try to access to my website with subdomain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) it doesn't show with https therefore my chrome browser doesn't allow me to view the page with subdomain.

How can I fix this?

*There's a minor detail that I suspect it may affect, I also added my Microsoft 365 Business records in the Azure DNS zone. (it has txt, MX, and CNAME records). In total, I have 3 CNAME records. 1 for Microsoft 365, 2 for the static web app. (Because it's a domain from google, I had to add custom nameservers, and it was the only way to add my Microsoft 365 records in my domain.)*

[image]

Comment: It is automatically added for the root domain from my webapp.

Comment: did you gone through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-azure-dns) for Setting up a custom domain with Azure DNS in Azure Static Web Apps?

Comment: Yes I followed the documentation. I updated my question with more details, could you check the question again?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the issue, follow the below steps

- After deploying the Azure static web app into the portal
- Goto **Custom domains** => click on **add** => click on **Custom domain on azure DNS** as shown below

[image]

[image]

- After clicking on Custom domain on azure DNS it will open a page where we have to enter **Domain name** example: `www.example.com` & **DNS name** we have to select from existing name Example: `example.com` => click on **Add** as shown below

[image]

- After successful deploying open the link in Crome, AFAIK static web App will take by default as HTTPS

[image]